# What is the symbolic meaning of the multiple serpent heads of Sheshanaga?

Tags: scripture, gods, balarama, naga

Vishnu rests on the body of Sheshanaga and Sheshanaga like Paramahansa rests on the ocean of bliss known as Prakriti. His being is depicted as having 5 or 7 or 1000 serpents. What is the symbolic meanings of these multiple serpent heads?

Comment: Sheshnag lies on the ocean, depending on the type of Vishnu you're talking. Vishnu and thereby Sheshnag are not affected by Prakriti in any way.

Comment: The so called answers are not satisfactory and usually do not address the question. What does one do ?

Comment: @The Crimson Universe, great insight and a marvel to behold but why 5,7 or 1000 Serpents ? Your answer is relevant to a previous question about reincarnation and the birth of Devas.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Comments are not for answering questions or discussing the topic, use chat room instead.

Comment: @Pandya. Totally agree. It adds so much negatively to the questions. Editing is a positive exercise.